# CakePHP Custom REST Routes

Tags: rest, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP and Backbone.js as a frontend so I want to get CakePHP's REST routing working, but I don't really want to use the default REST routes.

For example, I want to be able to POST to `http://example.com/cards/search.json` and get a list of results in JSON, however I am getting a 200 status code back, and a blank response which makes me think the routing is not working properly.

I have tested my code using the default REST routes by chagning the `search()` method of my controller to `add()`, but I would prefer to be able to properly setup and use custom REST routes.

```
Router::connect(
    "/cards/search",
    array(
        "[method]" => "POST",
        "controller" => "cards",
        "action" => "search"            
    )
);
Router::mapResources('cards');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

The code from my `routes.php` is above and I'm not entirely sure why it isn't working...either because the documentation on this is a little light, or I just don't understand routing very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the json output in this url:

```
http://localhost:{port}/{api* name in config @ app/core}/{controller name}/{things after api_ in function name}/{input parameters}.json
```

read more in [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

You may have to alter the routing to change the name 
 api
to anything in

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('master', 'api'));
```

in core.php in app/config 
Feel free for a comment and also share your core.php in config for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gunner, I'm still a bit confused though.  I dont have any Routing.Prefixes setup in my `core.php` file, the URL I list in my question looks like it should work based on the format you gave `http://sample.com/cards/search.json`, and the data being sent via `POST` I'm working with the `search()` action in `cards` controller.